# Creating a light trail effect by dynamically updating the curve of a TubeBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a third person game using react-three-fiber and I want to add a sort of trailing light effect wherever the player moves. The light trail will disappear after a while so I was thinking of having a fixed size array for the points. This was my initial attempt at a solution:

```
const point = new THREE.Vector3();
const points = new Array(50).fill(null).map(p => new THREE.Vector3());
let index = 0;


const Trail = () => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const playerBody = useStore(state => state.player); // contains player position

    const [path, setPath] = useState(new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points));
    useFrame(() => { // equivalent to raf
        const { x, y, z } = playerBody.position;
        point.set(x, y, z);

        points[index].copy(point);
        index = (index + 1) % 50;

        setPath(new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points));

        if (ref && ref.current) {
            ref.current.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
            ref.current.computeBoundingSphere();
        }
    });

    return (
        <mesh>
            <tubeBufferGeometry ref={ref} attach="geometry" args={[path, 20, .5, 8, false]} />
            <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color={0xffffff} />
        </mesh>
    )
}
```

Basically my thought process was to update the curve on every frame (or every x frames to be more performant) and to use an index to keep track of which position in the array of points to update.

However I get two problems with this:

1. TubeBufferGeometry doesn't update. Not sure if it's even possible to update the geometry after instantiation.
2. The pitfall I foresee in using this fixed array / index method is that once I hit the end of the array, I will have to wrap around to index 0. So then the curve interpolation would mess up because I'm assuming it takes the points sequentially. The last point in the array should connect to the first point now but it won't be like that.

To solve #2, I tried something like

```
points.unshift();
points.push(point.clone);
```

instead of `points[index].copy(point);` but I still couldn't get the Tube to update in the first place.

I wanted to see if there's a better solution for this or if this is the right approach for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the path of a TubeBufferGeometry, you also need to update all the vertices and normals, it is like building again the geometry.

Take a look here to understand how it works : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r118/src/geometries/TubeGeometry.js#L135

The important part is the `generateSegment()` function, and don't forget this part before :

```
    const frames = path.computeFrenetFrames( tubularSegments, closed );
```

I made an example last year, feel free to use my code : https://codepen.io/soju22/pen/JzzvbR